# Data in serial port looks corrupted after restarting service

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I have RasberryPi connected to Arduino via usb. Arduino is reading data from sensors and prints the data to serial port. I have server on Pi that reads serial port and pushes data to view.  I also have very simple deployment script which pushes my server application to Pi and restarts service. Deployment script looks like this,

```
USER_HOST="pi@192.168.178.34"
REMOTE_DIR="/home/pi/plantmonitor"
RAILS_DIR="/home/pi/plantmonitor/plantmonitorweb"
set -ue
cd plantmonitorweb
bundle exec rake tmp:clear
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
cd ..
rsync -rvuz ./ ${USER_HOST}:${REMOTE_DIR} --exclude='.git/' --exclude='log/' --exclude='tmp' --delete
ssh ${USER_HOST} 'sudo service plant restart'
echo "Deploy Successful!"
```

here is my init.d,

```
PROJECT=/home/pi/plantmonitor/plantmonitorweb
PIDFILE="${PROJECT}/tmp/pids/server.pid"

start() {
  if [ -f /var/run/$PIDFILE ] && kill -0 $(cat /var/run/$PIDFILE); then
    echo 'Service already running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo -n "Starting : "
  export SENSOR=true
  # export SECRET_KEY_BASE=
  export RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
  cd $PROJECT
  bundle exec rails s -e production -d > /tmp/plantservice.log 2>&1
  echo 'Service started'
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
    echo 'Service not running'
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Stopping service…'
  kill -15 $(cat "$PIDFILE") && rm -f "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service stopped'
}
```

After deployment data that I read from serial port becomes corrupted. To fix that issue I have restart PI. After I restart PI can read data normally again.

After restart data looks like this

> cat /dev/ttyACM0

> {"temperature": "24", "moisture": "10", "humidity": "50"}

After running deployment script data looks as follows,

`idity":3{"tidity":3{"tempe":37,"moemperatuisture":e":21,"hre":21}`

I am very curious why after service has restarted data I read from serial port changes.

Comment: What is your configuration on UART serial port in cmdline.txt? This looks like there is another service is using the console.

Comment: @hcheung could you elaborate why another service accessing file descriptor could corrupt data?  I think this could be the case. I am forking another process when I start server to read the data and when I'm restarting service I fail to kill forked process. I would like to know why that is corrupting data.

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1035/raspberry-pi-3-and-zero-w-serial-port-usage). Basically, you should check your `/boot/cmdline.txt` and remove the line `console=serial0,115200` to prevent the kernel using the serial port...